# Picture that lie between 2 section of a website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to learn html css by creating a simple website that i found and i want to make the picture lie between 2 section.

Just like in this picture, **picture lie between two section**

[image: picture lie between two section]

I want to know what is this type of design?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, so show what you got so far, or make an effort of your own and come back with that if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I created it but, i just want to know the type of design. Like how so you call this ? So that i don't have to say picture lie between two section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do it is to just set the tree's position as "relative".

You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) about the position property in CSS.

To define 2 sections here I have used a [div tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) :

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

#myImg {
  height : 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">

</div>

<div id="div2">

 <img id="myImg" src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180206/age/kisspng-tree-magnolia-christmas-nature-transparent-background-5a7a720d01efd2.8244164415179740290079.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, Do you know what this called ? like the type of design or the terminology of this ?

Comment: You're welcome, it doesn't really have a name. It's just "Positioning elements". And there are multiple ways to position them depending on what do you want to achieve.